# PISO shift register to USB

Tags: microcontroller, serial, uart, shift-register

I have ~26 parallel inputs that I would like serialize and send to a computer over USB. I decided to chain together 4 LS165 parallel-in serial-out shift registers, but I don't know how I would send this serial signal over USB. I considered using an FTDI FT232RL, but I'm not sure how I would make my serial signal into UART. I would like to avoid using a microcontroller in the middle if possible, but I will if it will make my life easier. Is there a simple way to take this basic serial stream and send it over USB?

Comment: Maybe you can use FT232H. It's a USB-GPIO chip, IIRC.

Comment: FT232R has "synchronous bitbang" mode for some IOs. Maybe you can make use of it?

Comment: There is a simple way to transfer 26 inputs over an RS232 to USB converter:  Use a microprocessor.

Comment: USB serial converters *are* MCUs, just running fixed programs from the factory (though there was one that secretly turned out to be reprogrammable).   It's likely the most compact and performant solution would be a USB-enabled MCU.  However your requirement is not really clear; in particular, what control do you need over the timing?  Generally USB is bad for "ask a question, get a response" interfaces (especially at bit level) and much better at data fed on the gadget's own timing, ie, "here, have this" "and this" "and this..."

Comment: @ChrisStratton There does not need to be any communication back to the device from the computer. Basically I want the PC to be constantly listening for data to know which inputs were received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively straightforward problem:

1. Create a small state machine to drive your parallel capture, serial clock and character serializer. This is very easy with a small ROM/EEPROM and a couple of multiplexers.
2. Transfer 3 bits at a time into another 4 * LS165 configured as a 3 character serializer. Configure the three characters as 'group' (char 'A' to 'I'), 'Value' (char '0' to '8'), CR (chare carriage return).
3. Create a baud rate generator to transfer your characters from the serializer and provide a clock for the state machine.
4. Clock the serial data into an FT232H configured as a UART to provide your serial to USB conversion.
5. For extra points, receive a serial command from the PC to start and stop your serializer.

All up about 15+ chips, but easy to layout.

**OR**

Use something like an Arduino Nano for about $4 (including USB connectors and cable) and write a few lines of code to transfer the data. You could even use the newer Arduino Micro based on the ATMega32u4 and get a single chip solution with USB connectivity for about the same price.

Instead of using TTL shift registers you'd be far better using something like the 16bit [MCP23017](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf) or the [PCA9671](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9671.pdf) I2C expanders, both readily supported and relatively cheap.

Comment: So it seems like the most cost effective approach would be to use a microcontroller like an arduino. I would still need to use some shift registers to serialize my data though, right? The arduino doesn't have 26 inputs I don't think.

Comment: There are plenty of MCUs which do have 26 inputs.  Depending on the nature of your input sensors you may be able to create a matrix like a keyboard uses.  Using shift registers as an I/O expander may yield lower parts cost than a high pin count MCU, but it will mean more complexity and that may dominate cost if you are not building many.

Comment: I decided to go with an AT90USB1286 because it has 46 I/O pins and integrated USB. Although it's a bit more expensive it will make my design really simple.

Comment: @sigsegv Good choice, I assume your are buying a Teensy++.